# UICollectionView Selection Lost When Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple `UICollectionView` up and running and have it so you can select a cell then save your selection. But guess what? I have a problem!

After scrolling the selected cell off-screen and back on, it looses its selection. Pretty simple at the surface. How can I stop this?

Is this something to do with cell reuse? Here is my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AircraftConfigurationCell";
    SLAircraftConfigurationCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Customise cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have a look at my post buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a datasource which is formed possibly from an array containing data models?

If so then you're off to a great start and can sort out this selection intermittent behaviour in no time!

In your data model `.h` file create a `property` like so `property (nonatomic, retain) BOOL selectedState;` and in the `.m` file initialise the `selectedState` to `FALSE` in your data object's init method.

Once that's done in your UICollectionView's `didSelect` method, set the dataObject's `selectedState` to `YES` that is associated to that cell/item index.

Then finally in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, ensure you do an if check on the dataModel instance that youre going to set the cellItem with for the `selectedState` property. If its set to `NO' set the selectionStyle to none, otherwise set it to yes.

I used to have your problem before where selection would be lost when scrolling, but now its being managed and the result is persistent.